# Are WASM networking requests visible in the browser's devtools?

Tags: networking, webassembly, devtools, emscripten

When networking in WASM (e.g. emscripten's socket support), are the network communications visible in the browser's devtools ?

Are there any WASM networking demo webapps available to test with ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no networking in Wasm itself. All such requests go through respective JavaScript wrappers imported into Wasm code. Since they call through JavaScript APIs, they should be visible in the same way as regular calls from within JS itself.