# How can I perform a set of crud REST api with tinygo?

Tags: go, webassembly, go-gin, tinygo

I'm currently working on a personal project. Notably to discover the possibilities of Web Assembly and Tinygo.

I have a small project which use vanilla.js and a simple index.html containing a button. When I click on the button, it execute my wasm module method `getBookById` which is exposed through my index.js file.

I have partially succeed in requesting an endpoint of my localhost backend server.

**main.go (front) :**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

// Call the backend server
//
//export getBookByID
func getBookByID(id int) {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:3001/books/" + strconv.Itoa(id))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
    if resp != nil {
        fmt.Println(resp)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Received nil response from server")
    }
}

func main() {
    println("Go wasm module is called")
}
```

**main.go (back) :**

```golang
// books slice to seed data records
var books = []book{
    {ID: "1", Title: "Sample title 1", Author: "Joe"},
    {ID: "2", Title: "Sample title 2", Author: "Michael"},
    {ID: "3", Title: "Sample title 3", Author: "John"},
}

// ....
// Return a Book by it's id
func getBookByID(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Param("id")

    for _, a := range books {
        if a.ID == id {
            c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, a)
            return
        }
    }
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "book not found"})
}
```

**I have the following log in my backend running with gin :**

```
[GIN] 2024/02/13 - 16:49:15 | 200 |     476.625µs |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/books/1"
```

And I can see in the browser "network" section, the response status from the server (200 OK)
**response content:**

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Sample title 1",
    "author": "Joe"
}
```

**But in my browser console, I have the following error :**

```
panic: runtime error: nil pointer dereference
main.wasm:0x55925 Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: unreachable
    at runtime.runtimePanicAt (main.wasm:0x55925)
    at runtime.nilPanic (main.wasm:0x775f)
    at runtime.chanSelect (main.wasm:0x71087)
    at interface:{RoundTrip:func:{pointer:named:net/http.Request}{pointer:named:net/http.Response,named:error}}.RoundTrip$invoke (main.wasm:0x1d5856)
    at getBookByID (main.wasm:0x202e02)
    at getBookByID.command_export (main.wasm:0x204c70)
    at getBookById (index.js:40:50)
    at async HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):161:24)
```

Is it due to a bad return type format ? Do I need to return my json as a string ?

Or should I use `syscall/js` to do an http call ?

Answer (score 1):

In the brwoser, WASM is not allowed to make network connections, at least not at this time.  All network requests would have to be made through a Javascript-side callback.

[Are WASM networking requests visible in the browser's devtools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279787/are-wasm-networking-requests-visible-in-the-browsers-devtools)

Comment: So currently the only solution is to call a javascript callback to do an http request ? So if I want to create and compile a go backend server. It will not be able to send http request even with a wasi runtime (ex: wasmtime) since it does not have anything related with a browser ?

Comment: correct.  Browser only limitation